# A more economical method of building an archive menu?

Tags: templating, elementcriteriamodel, performance, limit

I seem to be having trouble with the performance of my site (on localhost) after including this object. Im using it to build a menu for an archive of the posts section which has about 2,500 entries inside of it.

```
{% set allEntries = craft.entries.section('posts').limit(null) %}

{% for year, entriesInYear in allEntries | group("postDate.year") %}
    {{ year }}
{% endfor %}
```

This fetch request spits out the following:

> 2016 2015 2014 2013 2012 2011 2010 2009

When I make this fetch request, my page is reload time is ~11s. If I comment out this request my page reload time is ~3s.

Is there a more economical way to return the years associated with my posts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know which years should appear, and there are no breaks in the timeline, perhaps it would make more sense to do a simple numeric loop instead...

```
{% for year in (now.year)..2009 %}
    {{ year }}
{% endfor %}
```

That will count backwards from the current year to 2009.

Comment: Or you could use the oldest entry's postDate with `{% set oldestEntry = craft.entries.section('posts').order( 'postDate asc' ).first() %}` then use `oldestEntry.postDate|date( 'Y' )` is place of 2009.

Comment: NICE idea @Luke Pearce!

Comment: Great point @LukePearce! You could do the same to get the newest entry (in case it's not from the current year). So at most, you'd only be querying for 2 entries.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Lindsey and @LukePearce !